# Cheerio - get only text from html file

Tags: cheerio

I would like to know if there's a way to only get the text from an XTML loaded to Cherrio.

```
const html = cheerio.load(originalHtmlString);
```

how can I access just the content ? without needing to loop through each element.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
$('body').text()
```

or

```
$.root().text()
```

but it might not be as nicely formatted as you want.